# AngularJS form to PHP error 'Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined'

Tags: php, angularjs, forms

I'm getting this error when trying to post from an AngularJS control to a PHP page to process. The object looks fine, but it keeps giving this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at urlIsSameOrigin (angular.js:17714)
    at sendReq (angular.js:10225)
    at serverRequest (angular.js:9944)
    at processQueue (angular.js:14454)
    at angular.js:14470
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15719)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15530)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15824)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jcs-auto-validate.min.js:6)
    at HTMLFormElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3247)
```

Here is the code for the controller:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('contactApp')
        .controller('FormCtrl', FormCtrl);

    function FormCtrl ($http) {
        /* jshint validthis: true */
        var vm = this;

        vm.formModel = {};
        vm.success = false;
        vm.error = false;

        vm.onSubmit = function () {
            console.log("I'm submitted");
            console.log(vm.formModel);

            $http({
                method  :   'POST',
                URL     :   '/formProcess.php',
                data    :   {
                            'name':vm.formModel.name,
                            'phoneNumber':vm.formModel.phoneNumber,
                            'email':vm.formModel.email,
                            'streetAddress':vm.formModel.streetAddress,
                            'cityStateZip':vm.formModel.cityStateZip,
                            'bedrooms':vm.formModel.bedrooms,
                            'bath':vm.formModel.baths,
                            'reason':vm.formModel.reason
                            },
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                vm.resultData = data;
                alert("Message sent successfully. We'll get in touch with you soon.");

            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                vm.resultData = data;
                alert("Sending message failed.");
            });
            /*.success( function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if ( data.success ) {
                    vm.success = true;
                    console.log('happy');
                } else {
                    vm.error = true;
                    console.log('sad');
                }
            });*/
        }
    }
    FormCtrl.$inject = ['$http'];
})();
```

and for the PHP to send the email:

```
<?php

// ===========================================
// Define custom variables
// ===========================================
$emailTo = '---.com';
$nameTo  = 'test';
$subject = 'test';
// ===========================================
// Validate and send email
// ===========================================

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $response = array( 'success' => false );
    $formData = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
    $data = json_decode( $formData );
    /*if ( $data->submit ) {*/
        $name = $data->name;
        $phoneNumber = $data->phoneNumber;
        $email = $data->email;
        $streetAddress = $data->streetAddress;
        $cityStateZip = $data->cityStateZip;
        $bedrooms = $data->bedrooms;
        $baths = $data->baths;
        $reason = $data->reason;

        //check if any of the inputs are empty
        if ( $name != '' && $phoneNumber != '' && $email != '' && $streetAddress != '' && $cityStateZip != '' && $bedrooms != '' && $baths != '' && $reason != '' ) {
            $body = 'From: ' . $name . '\n';
            $body .= 'Email: ' . $email . '\n';
            $body .= 'Phone Number: ' . $phoneNumber . '\n';
            $body .= 'Street Address: ' . $streetAddress . '\n';
            $body .= 'City, State and Zip: ' . $cityStateZip . '\n';
            $body .= 'Number of Bedrooms: ' . $bedrooms . '\n';
            $body .= 'Number of Baths: ' . $baths . '\n';
            $body .= 'Reason for Selling:\n ' . $reason . '\n\n';
            $headers = 'From: '. $nameTo.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

            $success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

            if ( $success ) {
                $response[ 'success' ] = true;
            }
        }
    /*}*/
}

    echo json_encode( $response );
?>
```

Any thoughts as to what I might be missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `URL: '/formProcess.php',` to `url: '/formProcess.php',`

Comment: Holy ridiculousness! That was it. I'd have wasted a so much more time trying to chase that down. Thank you!